# Exponential performance drop in macOS with timegm(..) due to timezone lock

Tags: multithreading, macos, performance

In my application I experience an exponential slowdown due to a concurrent usage of `timegm` (at the moment around 800 times slower). I uploaded my test code here: http://cpp.sh/363nv

```
void* testThread(void* args)
{
    time_t tt;
    tm t;

    time(&tt);
    localtime_r(&tt, &t);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
    {
        timegm(&t);
    }

    return nullptr;
}
```

The performance drop is caused by a timezone lock. Any idea how to bypass this lock? Depending if I misuse `timegm(..)` or not, I will file a report to Apple. Thanks for any help

Here are my results:

**macOS 10.13.6 (Macbook Pro 2.5 GHz Intel Core i7):**

```
5000 calls of 'timegm' with 1 thread(s) took 0.03634 seconds
5000 calls of 'timegm' with 8 thread(s) took 24.84911 seconds
```

[image: performance]

For a comparison, here are the results of an online c++ execution:

**Linux:**

```
5000 calls of 'timegm' with 1 thread(s) took 0.00453 seconds                                                                  
5000 calls of 'timegm' with 8 thread(s) took 0.00588 seconds
```

Comment: I don't see the same issue on my system (albeit with a different OS version). In case it's helpful... on my Mid-2014 Macbook Pro with 2.5 GHz Intel Core i7 running 10.13.2, and using "Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.1)", I get numbers like 0.01668 and 0.03383 for the 1 and 8 thread scenarios, respectively.

Comment: By the way, you should put your full example code into the question above rather than an external site.